# compare two rows string holds "versions" in sqliteDB

Tags: sqlite

I have a table contains below schema.

```
CREATE TABLE apps (ENV TEXT,APP_NAME TEXT,APP_VERSION TEXT);
```

Holds data -

```
DEV|Application_1|1.2
DEV|Application_3|1.0
DEV|Applictaion_4|1.2
STAGE|Applictaion_1|0.2.3
STAGE|Application_2|1.0.2
STAGE|Application_3|1.0.3.4
```

I want to compare two rows from diff environment for `app_version` column like below example

**Example:** 
I am trying to list all `app_name` with lower `app_version` in DEV environment compare to STAGE environment, for which I am executing below query in SQLite DB but its showing incorrect data

```
select distinct a.* from (select app_name,app_version from apps where env = "DEV") a join (select app_name,app_version from apps where env = "STAGE") b on a.app_name = b.app_name and a.app_version < b.app_version;
```

**Expected Result:**

```
DEV|Application_3|1.0
```

Comment: What is the specific row that is compared wrong?

Comment: By example data, I wanted to get help if SQLite can compare loosed versions, as from real data I am getting lots of rows are compared wrong, and in this example, I am getting - 
`DEV|Application_1|1.2
DEV|Application_3|1.0`

Comment: Those are different names; this should not happen. Please provide a [mcve] (on [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!5) or so).